# ¿Cómo poner una linea horizontal en facetas?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, gráficas, referencias

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
datos_2 <- data.frame(fecha = seq.Date(ymd("2017-08-15"), ymd("2017-08-27"), length.out = 14), temperatura = c(25.0, 26.7, 26.6, 25.2, 25.1, 27.6, 27.0, 28.8, 26.2, 24.3, 24.4, 24.8, 24.7, 26.3), humedad_rel = c(88.8, 86.7, 86.1, 86.4, 86.9, 88.7, 89.1, 85.8, 90.9, 88.0, 85.7, 87.4, 84.9, 84.9), fluctuacion_tronco = c(297.7, 278.9, 251.7, 231.3, 270.9, 346.4, 342.1, 331.7, 370.0, 283.5, 186.4, 255.6, 189.5, 193.0))
```

Y utilizo el siguiente código para obtener un gráfico en facetas:

```
datos_2<- gather(data = datos_2, key = "variable", value = "valor", -fecha)

    ggplot(datos_2, aes(x = fecha, y = valor)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = datos_2$fecha, date_breaks = "2 days") + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y", 
             strip.position = "left") + 
  labs(x = "Fecha", 
       y = NULL, 
       title = "Contracción Diaria del Tronco (CDT) vs Factores", 
       subtitle = "Gráfico por día") + 
  theme_light() + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8))
```

Y obtengo el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito "partir" el gráfico en dos, ya que la fecha 2017-08-18 marca dos temporadas distintas para mi estudio, pensé en hacer una linea vertical con geom_vline pero solo he conseguido romperme la cabeza buscando el error (u horror), ayuda por favor, en:

1. Hacer una linea vertical que divida todo el gráfico en la fecha 2017-08-18, y
2. Poner una anotación dentro del gráfico, en el cual pueda indicar algo como "temporada 1" y "temporada 2".

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de los problemas que tienes, es que usas escalas libres en `y`, entonces para hacer una anotación como un texto y posicionar el mismo en una coordenada `x, y` debes calcular esto por cada grupo. Por ejemplo:

```
datos_2 %>% 
  mutate(temporada = factor(ifelse(datos_2$fecha <= '2017-08-18', 'Temporada 1', "Temporada 2")),
         x = as.Date(ifelse(datos_2$fecha <= '2017-08-18', '2017-08-17', '2017-08-19'))) %>% 
  left_join(datos_2 %>%
              group_by(variable) %>% 
              summarise(y = max(valor)), by = "variable")  %>% 
  group_by(variable, temporada, x, y) %>%
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(variable, temporada, x, y) -> datos_anotaciones

datos_anotaciones

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  variable           temporada   x              y
  <chr>              <fct>       <date>     <dbl>
1 fluctuacion_tronco Temporada 1 2017-08-17 370  
2 fluctuacion_tronco Temporada 2 2017-08-19 370  
3 humedad_rel        Temporada 1 2017-08-17  90.9
4 humedad_rel        Temporada 2 2017-08-19  90.9
5 temperatura        Temporada 1 2017-08-17  28.8
6 temperatura        Temporada 2 2017-08-19  28.8
```

Los datos, creo que se entienden, son los textos para cada variable y su posición `x` e `y`. La linea vertical es simple, ya que la escala del eje horizontal es la misma:

```
  geom_vline(linetype="dotted", 
             size=1.5,
             mapping=aes(xintercept=as.Date('2017-08-18'))) +
```

simplemente "mapeamos" el parámetro `xintercept` con la fecha en cuestión. Para los textos, con los datos anteriores podemos hacer:

```
  geom_text(data=datos_anotaciones,
            mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, label=temporada)) +
```

Para este `geom` usamos nuestro nuevo `data.frame`, las variables de este se mapean a los atributos estéticos del `geom_text()`.

Finalmente:

```
datos_2 %>% 
  mutate(temporada = factor(ifelse(datos_2$fecha <= '2017-08-18', 'Temporada 1', "Temporada 2")),
         x = as.Date(ifelse(datos_2$fecha <= '2017-08-18', '2017-08-17', '2017-08-19'))) %>% 
  left_join(datos_2 %>%
              group_by(variable) %>% 
              summarise(y = max(valor)), by = "variable")  %>% 
  group_by(variable, temporada, x, y) %>%
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(variable, temporada, x, y) -> datos_anotaciones


ggplot(datos_2, aes(x = fecha, y = valor)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = datos_2$fecha, date_breaks = "2 days") + 
  labs(x = "Fecha", 
       y = NULL, 
       title = "Contracción Diaria del Tronco (CDT) vs Factores", 
       subtitle = "Gráfico por día") + 
  theme_light() + 

  geom_vline(linetype="dotted", 
             size=1.5,
             mapping=aes(xintercept=as.Date('2017-08-18'))) +

  geom_text(data=datos_anotaciones,
            mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, label=temporada)) +

  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y", 
             strip.position = "left") + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Patricio, fue de mucha ayuda!